# Antlr4: lexer rule fails where parser rule succeeds?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have a rule that matches strings when it's a parser (lowercase) rule, but not when it's a lexer (uppercase) rule. Here's the code:

```js
not_combat
    : (ownership|'the') PHASES
    ;

ownership
    : SELECTIVES (player_opponent'\'s'?)? // this needs to be a parser rule, fails on lexer rule... dunno why.
    ;

SELECTIVES
    : 'your'|'each'|'that'
    ;

player_opponent
    : 'player'|'opponent'
    ;
```

I'm running the Antlr4 plugin in IntelliJ Idea, using the built-in rule tester and parse tree. My test string is `each player's upkeep`, where the `player_opponent` parser rule will work, but the lexer `Player_opponent` rule will fail with string `player`, but not with string `opponent`, which is the really confusing part to me.

Comment: If you're simply changing `ownership` into a lexer rule then you are referencing a parser rule (`player_opponent`) from within a lexer rule which doesn't make much sense. But I have no clue why it works with `opponent`as an input though.

Comment: Can't help : 6 token recognition error, missing PHASES at '<EOF>'.  You should at least provide the necessary grammar to parse the given input.